# Moviepy generating GIFs from the same point

Tags: python, python-2.7, moviepy

I have tried to generate a simple GIF file from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynF6JjE3wyA) video. My code is below:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
clip = (VideoFileClip("Mighty Kungfu Panda 'Skadoosh'.mp4").subclip((0,0.18),(0,0.21)).resize(0.3))
clip.write_gif("skadoosh2.gif")
```

But GIF is not generating properly. All i can see, an image of the starting scene of the clip. I have tried different parameters with **subclip()**. But the result has remained same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that 0.18 and 0.21 refer to fractions of seconds, so you are asking for a clip of duration 0.03 !!

Instead, if you want the clip between t=18s and t=21s, use subclip(18, 21)

Comment: thanks my problem is solved. And extra thanks to answer this question personally, as you are the creator of Moviepy. :)